# Matplotlib mlab: change psd() maximum frequency?

Tags: python, matplotlib, fft, spectrogram

I only just discovered the awesome that is [`matplotlib.mlab.psd()`](http://matplotlib.org/api/mlab_api.html#matplotlib.mlab.psd), but I am having one issue, that is: **how can I change the frequency range used by the method?**

This has two return values: `freqs`, which is pretty much the histogram bins for various frequencies, and `Pxx`, the normalized power at each frequency bin. `freqs` ranges in [0, 100] Hz. I can change the resolution using the parameter `pad_to`, but I can't change the range to be, say, [0, 20]. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The frequency range is set by the sampling details of your data, this is a property of the FFT.

The lowest frequency is set by the length of your data (in this case by `NFFT` which sets your window size), and the highest frequency is set by your sampling frequency.

Comment: Ahh, I believe I conceptualized it incorrectly. Thank you for your cogent explanation!